# Python Script to copy CSV files and save as XLSX files

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a series of csv files in a specific folder on my computer. Need to write a python code to pick those CSV files and extract them into another designated folder on my drive as XLSX. On each file, Column L,M,N is formatted as Date. Column AA & AF is formatted as Number. Other columns can be stored as text or General. 
Here is some code i got stuck at

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save('name.xlsx')
```

Comment: this code above works fine, for one csv file. What's your issue?

Comment: My issue is that i have multiple CSV's and it just extracts the XLSX as all text. i need to format the output columns L,M,N in each file as Date and Column AA, AF as Number.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas this task should be quite simple.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

You can do that for any amount of files by changing the strings to the appropriate filenames.

## Edit

I am not sure if you can save by the desired type. You may be able to change that using another package or even pandas. In pandas you can perform `pd.to_dateime` or `pd.to_numeric` on a Series to change its type. You can also specify `dtype` when importing. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

the solution should be something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dpath = 'path//to//folder'
for filename in os.listdir('dpath'):
    df = pd.read_csv(path + '/' + filename)
    df = df['a':'b'] #select required columns based on your requirement.
    df["a"] = pd.to_numeric(df["a"]) # convert datatype of the column based on your need
    df1.append(df)
    del df

df1.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```